# PHP Simple Html Dom get the plain text of div，but avoiding all other tags

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I use PHP Simple Html Dom to get some html,now i have a html dom like follow code,i need fetch the  plain text inner div,but avoiding the p tags and their content（only return 111111）, who can help me?Thanks in advance!

```
<div>
    <p>00000000</p>
    111111
    <p>22222222</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "avoiding the p tags".

If you just want to remove the tags, then just running [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) on it should work for what you want.

If you actually want to just return "11111" (ie. strip the tags **and their contents**) then this isn't a viable solution. For that, something like this **may** work:

```
$myDiv = $html->find('div'); // wherever your the div you're ending up with is
$children = $myDiv->children; // get an array of children
foreach ($children AS $child) {
    $child->outertext = ''; // This removes the element, but MAY NOT remove it from the original $myDiv
}
echo $myDiv->innertext;
```

Comment: I only want to return 111111.How to achieve？

Comment: Edited with a POSSIBLE fix, although I can't guarantee it'll work. I don't have a SHD document to work with and test on

Answer (score 8):

If you text is always at the same position , try this:

```
$html->find('text', 2)->plaintext; // should return 111111
```

Comment: According to the manual ( http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm ) in the "How to access the HTML element's attributes?" section and "Magic attributes" tab, this will return the contents of the inner tags too, just with the actual tags themselves

Comment: Ah, I see. Fair enough :-)

Comment: This should be : $html->find('text', 1)->plaintext; to get 111111

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution

[image]

I want to get the Primary Text part only.

```
 $title_obj = $article->find(".ofr-descptxt",0); //Store the Original Tree  ie) h3 tag
 $title_obj->children(0)->outertext = ""; //Unset <br/>
 $title_obj->children(1)->outertext = "";  //Unset the last Span
 echo $title_obj; //It has only first element
```

Edited:
If you have PHP errors
Try to enclose with If else or try my lazy code

```
   ($title_obj->children(0))?$title_obj->children(0)->outertext="":"";
   ($title_obj->children(1))?$title_obj->children(1)->outertext = "":"";
```

[Official Documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
$wordlist = array("<p>", "</p>")

foreach($wordlist as $word)
     $string = str_replace($word, "", $string);
```

Comment: Have fun adding every possible HTML tag into the wordlist :-)