# Get h2 html using Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have the HTML web page with this code:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 xs-box2">
    <h2 class="title-medium br-bottom">Your Name</h2>
</div>
```

Now I want to use Simple HTML DOM Parser to get the text value of h2 in this div.
My code is:

```
$name = $html->find('h2[class="title-medium br-bottom"]');
echo $name;
```

But it always return an error: "

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 21
Array
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `$name` is not a string and you can't `echo` it. Try `print_r` maybe to check?

Comment: Now with print_r($name), it's return "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65015808 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 21"

Comment: You need to use `$name->plaintext`. Check [PHP Simple Html Dom get the plain text of div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25663025/5104748)

Comment: One thing to be very careful about is when using class attributes to find data, they can be easily changed by the page developers and suddenly your code fails to load this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try for `Simple HTML DOM`

```
 foreach($html->find('h2') as $element){
    $element->class;
 }
```

There are other methods to parse

**Method 1.**

You can get the `H2` tags using the following code snippet, using `DOMDocument` and `getElementsByTagName`

```
$received_str = '<div class="col-sm-9 xs-box2">
  <h2 class="title-medium br-bottom">Your Name</h2>
</div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($received_str);
$h2tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');
foreach ($h2tags as $_h2){
  echo $_h2->getAttribute('class');
  echo $_h2->nodeValue;
}
```

**Method2**

Using the `Xpath` you can parse it

```
$received_str = '<div class="col-sm-9 xs-box2">
    <h2 class="title-medium br-bottom">Your Name</h2>
</div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($received_str);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//h2[@class='title-medium br-bottom']");
header("Content-type: text/plain");
foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
    $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Why you trying to use `DomDocument` when there is simpler why using **Simple HTML** that OP used it?

Comment: @Mohammad I have updated my solution for SImple HTML